# Nagios Statistics for Notifications/Alerts

Tags: nagios

We have had our Nagios installation up for a year, and we are now required to give some statistics on how much it has worked and what it has done in the environment. As such, I was wondering if anyone knows if Nagios also holds data records on how many alerts and notifications it sends out?  I am not necessarily looking for reports on what it alerted on, but just some raw statistics for a powerpoint.
TL:DR
Can I extract how many notifications and alerts Nagios has produced in it's existence or between certain dates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

open up your nagios console

- Select Reports > Alerts > Summary
- Under Custom Report Options, Set Report Type to "Alert Totals" (or one of the options like this for finer grained reporting
- Set the Report Period to "* CUSTOM REPORT PERIOD *"
- Set the start date and end dates appropriately
- Apply any other filters that you would like (hostgroups, hosts etc)
- It is not necessary to adjust Max List Items as this report is quite short.
- Click on Create Summary Report

Done!

This is valid for Nagios 3.2.0

Comment: Wow... 5 years using Nagios, and I never thought to use that.  Worked like a charm!!!!  I also received similar results by running this command that someone responded me to in the nagios-users mailing list

grep NOTIFICATION /usr/local/nagios/var/archives/*2010*.log | wc -l

Comment: The only reason I know is that I had to use the reporting tool to calculate uptimes for SLA compliance so I became reasonably familiar with the reporting section. +1 for you though for getting the command line grep!

Comment: Well, I haven't actually got it to work 100% yet (it times out) but when I did the grep, it did pull up 100k notifications for the time period... Also I am using like 3.02B I think.  But It will work eventually.